# How to select specific lines regardless on the content in the middle

Tags: regex, notepad++

Let's start with the structure I have so that I can better explain what I want to do. Imagine that I have a text as it follows:

```
write information1/info_a/content
read information/content
write information1/info_b/content
write information1/info_c/content
write information2/info_a/content
write information2/info_b/content
write information3/format/info_b/content
```

I want to highlight every line that starts with a specific path and that also contains another path, for example:

- starts with 'write'
- and contains 'info_b'

The desired output with the give example above is then:

```
write information1/info_b/content
write information2/info_b/content
write information3/format/info_b/content
```

How can I do this with a regular expression?

Thanks to everybody in advance

I know that for selecting everything that starts with write with regex I can do:

^write

and that for saying until the end of the line I should use the key $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select any line containing "info_b" with the regex:

```
^write.*info_b.*$
```

Which translates to line start-> any amount of anything -> info_b -> any amount of anything -> end line